# How to modify the connection string in Excel 365

Tags: excel-2016

We have an internally developed tool that can modify the connection strings inside of an Excel 2016 workbook. The tool uses a library provided by Microsoft to access the various parts of an open XML document/file. However, the connection string inside a workbook constructed with Excel 365 appears to store the data source and the command (SQL query) as pointers to a location inside an encrypted string inside the Excel file (.xlsx).

Has anyone been successful in modifying the connection string from an Excel 365 workbook?

Our internal tool uses c# to access the Excel 2016 file.